# cache passcode for python snowflake connector

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, multi-factor-authentication, duosecurity

To connect with my snowflake db, I authenticate using a passcode (with Duo) since MFA is enabled

```
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='',
    password='',
    account='',
    warehouse='',
    database='',
    schema='',
    passcode='011415'
)
```

However, every time, I want to run my python script, I need to refresh the passcode from the Duo app and re-enter the new one in the script.

Is there any way I can avoid repeating the step everytime? Can the passcode be cahced?

For example, when I use Dbeaver, it sends a notification to my Duo app and once I approve it, I dont need to re-authenticate there for the next 24 hours, unless I turn off the computer of course.

Answer (score 0):

[Python Connector - Using Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-multi-factor-authentication-mfa)

> Snowflake supports caching MFA tokens, including combining MFA token caching with SSO.

[Using MFA Token Caching to Minimize the Number of Prompts During Authentication — Optional](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-mfa.html#label-mfa-token-caching)

> MFA token caching can help to reduce the number of prompts that must be acknowledged while connecting and authenticating to Snowflake, especially when multiple connection attempts are made within a relatively short time interval.
>
> **A cached MFA token is valid for up to four hours.**

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer as well, if anyone is looking for it in the future.

This solution is not in the official doc, but you can use [client_request_mfa_token](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/f2d398a6e15ac108c280c6053bd8f1fbacc0d605/src/snowflake/connector/connection.py#L183). [DBT](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/blob/efe2eba0b45d0549576831c366e3815b899a7d3a/dbt/adapters/snowflake/connections.py#L158-L159) uses the same kind of pattern for their snowflake connector.

Note that as per the doc, you have a 4 hour caching period max.

> With certain Snowflake-provided clients, you can cache MFA tokens for up to four hours. For more information, see [Using MFA Token Caching to Minimize the Number of Prompts During Authentication — Optional](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-mfa#label-mfa-token-caching).

```py
kawrgs = {
    "authenticator": "externalbrowser",
    "client_request_mfa_token": True,
    # ...

}
with snowflake.connector.connect(**kawrgs):
    pass
```